# Sitecore 8 Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.5, sitecore-xdb

I am using Sitecore 8 and after I stopped the MongoDB service and set the setting in configs to stop using MongoDB for analytics this specific error:

```
ERROR Exception while handling event Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback
   at Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback.Providers.FallbackLanguageProvider.ClearFallbackCaches(ItemUri itemUri, Database database)
   at Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback.Providers.FallbackLanguageProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1.<InitializeEventHandlers>b__0(PublishEndRemoteEvent event)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event, Type eventType, EventContext context)
```

To disable the Analytics database I've used the indications from [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641).

Does PublishEndRemoteEvent use somehow MongoDB? Do you know how can I fix this so I won't get it anymore?

Comment: Could you check in `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` what is the setting for `SupportedDatabases` for your `FallbackLanguageProvider`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak  the showConfig looks like https://github.com/leethomascook/SitecoreMVC/blob/master/Aqueduct.BaseSitecoreMVCSite/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx and I was not able to find showConfig.aspx.cs to see more details

Comment: My question was about what do you see when you navigate to `http://localhost/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` (or using your host name instead of localhost)

Comment: @MarekMusielak the setting is master|web like <SupportedDatabases patch:source="Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback.config">master|web</SupportedDatabases>

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a new assembly for Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback with the following change:

Update the below file as follows:
Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback/Providers/FallbackLanguageProvider.cs

```
private void ClearFallbackCaches(ItemUri itemUri, Database database)  {
 var cache = _fallbackValuesCaches[database.Name];
 var ignore_cache = _fallbackIgnoreCaches[database.Name];

 if (cache != null)
 {
     // Added a null check on itemUri
     if (itemUri == null)
         cache.Clear();
     else
         cache.RemoveKeysContaining(itemUri.ItemID.ToString());
 }
 if (ignore_cache != null)
 {
     // Added a null check on itemUri
     if (itemUri == null)
         ignore_cache.Clear();
     else
         ignore_cache.RemoveKeysContaining(itemUri.ItemID.ToString());
 }  }
```

https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2014/05/03/sitecore-partial-language-fallback-cache-clearing-issue/